# Expect_equal() with empty string

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I want to **test a function** with **expect_equal()** from the **testthat** package in R that extracts information from a string separated by `|`. I also want to test the case when the input string is empty. However, in this case **I do not achieve the expected equality** (see code snippet below). I get the error "*Error: `result` not equal to `expected`.
Component “info2”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 1 in target*". How to solve this?

```
library(stringr)
library(testthat)


# Function to be tested
fn_extract_info <- function(some_text) {
  
  info1 <- unlist(
    stringr::str_split(
      some_text, "\\|"))[1]
  
  info2 <- unlist(
    stringr::str_split(
      some_text, "\\|"))[2]
  
  return(list(
    info1 = info1,
    info2 = info2
  ))
  
}

# Test function
fn_test_fn_extract_info <- function(some_text, expected) {
  
  result <- fn_extract_info(some_text = some_text)
  
  expect_equal(result, expected)
  
}

# Execution of test function with empty string
fn_test_fn_extract_info(
  some_text = "", 
  expected = list(info1 = "",
                  info2 = "NA")
  )
```

The function fn_extract_info() with an empty string as input produces:

```
$info1
[1] ""

$info2
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `"NA"` is not the same as `NA`. And also not all `NA` values are created the same. If you are expecting a missing character value, you should run this instead

```
fn_test_fn_extract_info(
  some_text = "", 
  expected = list(info1 = "",
                  info2 = NA_character_)
)
```

`NA_character_` is the special typed version of `NA` for character values.